gcc12 from gcc11 slow static const std::map compilation
I have a very large std::map that under gcc 11 takes about 3 minutes to compile, but gcc 12 takes over an hour. The key info is that the map has over 60000 entries in it.
building is undertaken in a docker container, for both gcc 11 and gcc 12, with gcc 11 being centos 7 and gcc 12 being rocky 9.
sample is
static const std::map<std::string, std::string> my_map = {{"str1", "val1"}, .... {"str60000", "val60000" }};

Is there anything I should be doing with g++ to get the compile times down?
I have tried splitting the std::map up, but seems to have little affect on compile times. I have also used different optimisation levels and c++ standards (17 and 20) but again no affect. I have also tried std::unordered_map, but again no luck.

Might want to check whether you're running out of memory

Thanks, I had been checking that and all looks ok, a lot is being used but still only about 10% of what is available, ulimit is set to unlimited as well so it does not look like g++ is being limited in any way.

Are you able to test with later versions of gcc?  Could just be a performance regression bug that perhaps was fixed later.

A possible workaround would just be to define a static array of strings, and use it to populate your map at runtime.  I'd expect that to compile very fast, and probably not take all that much runtime either.

good point re later gcc versions, I will give that a try, thanks

Moving to gcc 13 worked, thanks @NateEldredge for your suggestion.
